# Set column width Excel export php

Tags: php, excel, export

I have a form for excel export using php.Now code working well but all column seems same width.I want to set column width but how can i set that.here is my code

```
<form style="display:none" id="sendtable" action="<?php echo PRODUCTS . 'downloadexcel' ?>" method="post">
<input type="button" name="Export Excel"
     value="Export Excel" onclick="callexports();"/>
<div id="tabledata">
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  table#t01 {
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: #f1f1c1;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <colgroup width="80%" style="background-color: green;">
    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <colgroup width="80%" style="background-color: red;">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Action Items</th>
    <th>Assigned to</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>End date date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php
    if (isset($this->getallactionitems)):
       $i = 1;
       foreach ($this->getallactionitems as $details):
     ?>
     <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
     <td style="width: 80%;">
       <?php echo $details['Actions']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $details['Assigned_to']  ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $details['Start_date']  ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $details['End_date']  ?></td>
  </tr>
     <?php $i++ ?>
     <?php endforeach;
        endif; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
</body>
<input type="hidden" name="tableval" id="tableval" />
</form>
```

function download:

```
public function downloadexcel() {
        $filename = "Actionitems" . time(); //File Name
        $file_ending = "doc";
//header info for browser
        header("Content-type:application/vnd.msword");
//    header("Expires:0");//no cache
//    header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0");//no cache
//    header("content-disposition:attachment;filename=sampleword.xlxs");
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        Echo $_REQUEST['tableval'];
}
```

Which is working well..but i want to set B column width using this code.Now all column width seems same width.How to set column width?please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this package out, it's great for working with excel files, and it has great documentation. You won't have to build your own excel file, only pass the data as an array to the library.

https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel